# Ringing key cities - meaning of "ringing"?

Tags: meaning

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/aleksandar-vasovic-rebel-commander-warns-of-attack-2014-5

> The Ukrainian checkpoints on main roads and **ringing** key cities do appear vulnerable and many have been attacked already, some changing hands many times.

What is **ringing** supposed to mean in that sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Ringing" means "making rings around" or "making a ring around".  So "The Ukrainian checkpoints [...] ringing key cities do appear vulnerable [....]" is "The Ukrainian checkpoints making rings around key cities do appear vulnerable [....]".

Comment: You might want to say, "The Ukrainian checkpoints that **circle around** key cities do appear vulnerable." It's the thing about not using the word within it's own definition.

Answer (score 2):

It refers to checkpoints that surround cities. These surrounding checkpoints are part of a "ring" or circle that goes around the city of Donetsk that is in the center and being referred to in the article.

Comment: Not quite. "Ringing" in this example refers the checkpoints.  It's checkpoints ringing key cities, not key cities that ring something.

Comment: Ah, that's correct, it is referring to the checkpoints themselves not cities.